# Como recuperar la ruta de una imagen en Base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, imagen, url

Tengo un problema al recuperar la ruta de una imagen en mi base de datos, la imagen se sube correctamente, la ruta se captura bien, solo que al principio sale la palabra **Array**, y no tengo idea porque, necesito que no diga eso para poder utilizar la url después y mostrar la imagen.

Así se manda a mi base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que sube la imagen al servidor:

**subir.php**

```
<?php

$type=$_FILES['img_up']['type'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['img_up']["tmp_name"];
$name = $_FILES['img_up']["name"];
$nuevo_path="images/".$name;
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$nuevo_path);
$array=explode('.',$nuevo_path);
$ext= end($array);
echo "<h3>La imagen se subio correctamente</h3>";

?>
```

Y en otro php recupero la ruta:

```
  $imagen=$_POST.$nuevo_path;

  $insertar="INSERT INTO events VALUES('$id', '$fecha', '$ciudad', '$estado', '$info', '$costo', '$imagen')";
```

Nota: omitir las demás variables pues en ellas no hay ningún problema, solo con la variable $imagen.

No soy experto, es un trabajo escolar, pero ya llevo varias horas intentando y no se recupera bien la url, sé que hay muchos ejemplos en internet pero ninguno me sirve para basarme.

Comment: Lo que primero que me hace ruido, es ese `$_POST` concatenado a tu variable `$nuevo_path`... Ese es el que te genera la palabra "Array" en tu texto. ¿Por qué lo estás concatenando a `$nuevo_path`?

Comment: Ya esta, era eso, solo debía poner $imagen=$nuevo_path;